# add a route for VPN with NetworkManager

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, vpnc

Is it possible to add a route with NetworkManager for a VPN connection by using an interface name instead of a gateway address?

I don't know an IP of my gateway after I'm connected to the VPN server, so I manually add a couple routes with

```
ip r add 10.1.0.0 dev tun0
ip r add 10.2.0.0 dev tun0
```

Looking for a way to make it happening automatically, preferably with NetworkManager, if not then with some post-up script.

TIA!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, `ip r add 10.1.0.0 dev tun0` adds a "device route". That is, there is no gateway—meaning the gateway is `0.0.0.0`.

In Network Manager just configure `0.0.0.0` as gateway.

What you currently cannot do with Network Manager is to use special wildcards to refer to the actual gateway as provided from the VPN (or DHCP, autoconf). Similar to OpenVPN's special names `vpn_gateway` or `net_gateway`.